# Spark Avro Throws : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-avro

I am trying to create a dataframe and write the result in avro format. This is giving the IllegalArgumentException exception as mentioned in the subject. It is working correctly if I am saving it as text file but failing while writing avro.
Using the java api of spark. Using spark-submit.
Note: This error is not coming when scala or spark-shell is used.

```java
DataFrame test = sqlContext.createDataFrame(foo,bar.class);
test.write().format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save(outLoc);
```

Dependencies Used :-

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-avro_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the stack trace :-

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 12 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 12.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 737, vp21q40ic-hpao081322.me.com): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$SQLContext$$beansToRows$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$SQLContext$$beansToRows$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1365)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$SQLContext$$beansToRows$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$SQLContext$$beansToRows$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1363)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:263)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

ok.. so this is not a code issue. I have tried the same using spark-submit command and works well for me. The only thing I had done is- I have copied  the jar file (spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar) got after adding the maven dependency to my pom to my lib folder(containg all the external jars). "part-00000-3a5cbfc6-5234-40dd-8510-d67370c5f2e4.avro" got generated. 
Please check the version compatibility.